# How do I install thymeleaf without using maven in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How do I install [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) without using maven in Spring? Most of the information out there is based using maven. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new empty project. Install thymeleaf (and spring) with maven as described in the official links, put your dependencies.

Open your pom.xml and add [maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html).

Open a command prompt/shell and get your project jars with the command below

```
mvn dependency:copy
```

Now you will have all needed jars in one place.

Now for your question, include all of these in your project classpath and everything should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Like any project, if you want to use it without Maven, you have to manually download the jar (and any dependencies) and add it to the classpath of your project. The dependencies are listed on the download page http://www.thymeleaf.org/download.html

Comment: Just download the distribution zip linked from http://www.thymeleaf.org/download.html - all the dependencies are included.